# How to disable rows (make read only rows) based on a property of row data in Ag-grid

Tags: rows, ag-grid

Can not find a way to disable data rows based on a property on the data for each row. In other words, make few rows of the grid read-only based of some property in the row data of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than setting `editable: true` I'm setting `editable` based on the data:

`editable: params => params.data.active === true`